# Laravel treating decimal as string

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im trying to make the next eloquent query

```
$result = $result->where('money','>=',(float)$moneyFilter);
```

The money column in my database its DECIMAL(11,2), when I run the query it returns an empty array, when I go over php artisan tinker and see the column money, it's a string value "11.1".

I would like to filter the $result collection to have values over $moneyFilter.

Thanks

Comment: Eloquents [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) and their attribute casting might be helpful in this situation.

Comment: Maybe.. But why is it so in the first place?

Comment: `echo (float)'10000000000.9999';` => `10000000001`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define in your model which fields need to be cast to a primitive attribute.

```
  protected $casts = ['my_decimal' => 'float'];
```

There is a really good explanation here:

https://mattstauffer.com/blog/laravel-5.0-eloquent-attribute-casting/

Also there is an explanation in the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: Casting a `decimal` value to `float` is only a good solution if you don't care about the accuracy of the value

Comment: I wonder what happens if you save a model with a float value with more decimals than the decimal in the db?