# SQL Query returns my numbers into strings instead of integers

Tags: mysql, laravel

When I sort my table by column I saw that my sort was wrong for my numbers because my numbers were strings. I found a solution to do **CAST(COALESCE(p.total,0) AS UNSIGNED)** and now it returns them as an integer. I think it's very inconvenient that I need to do this to all my numbers? Can somebody explain me why it does behave like that or what I do wrong?

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw(
    "SELECT i.date,
    u.type,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', u.first_name, u.last_name) AS consultant,
    c.name AS customer,
    CAST(COALESCE(e.pp,0) AS UNSIGNED) AS pp,
    CAST(COALESCE(e.sp,0) AS UNSIGNED) AS sp,
    CAST(COALESCE(e.sp,0) - COALESCE(e.pp,0) AS UNSIGNED) AS margin,
    CAST(COALESCE(p.total,0) AS UNSIGNED) AS total_purchase,
    CAST(COALESCE(i.total, 0) AS UNSIGNED) AS total_sales,
    CAST(COALESCE(i.total,0) - COALESCE(p.total,0) AS UNSIGNED) AS gross_margin
    FROM clockwork.invoices AS i
    INNER JOIN clockwork.timesheets AS t ON i.timesheet_id = t.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clockwork.purchases AS p ON t.id = p.timesheet_id
    INNER JOIN clockwork.users AS u ON i.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN clockwork.customers AS c ON i.customer_id = c.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clockwork.contract_extensions AS e ON i.extension_id = e.id
    WHERE i.date between '$request->start' and '$request->end'
    GROUP BY i.date, u.type, u.first_name, u.last_name, c.name, e.pp, e.sp, p.total, i.total
    ORDER BY u.first_name
"));
```

Comment: Is column datatype integer?

Comment: @Samir my datatypes are decimals

Comment: Do you think it is possible to do your cast after the request within your variable properties ?

Comment: @MounirOnGithub I can do that but I want to understand why my numbers are converted to strings.

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work. I don't see where you sort by numbers.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The sort works because I cast the numbers to unsigned. My question is why my query converts my decimals into strings because they have the right datatype in the db. I want to know this so that I don't have to cast all my numbers to unsigned/signed in my raw query.

Comment: So are you sorting in PHP? If so - why not in SQL? It [works just fine](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wd7ZmnJsXiP8NMfnM8UMjM/0)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I sort with a Vue component that can sort my table per column. So I can't pre-sort.

Comment: Well .. The problem is that PHP does not have a numeric type which can reliably map MySQL's DECIMALs. `float` can lose precision. Try `echo (float)'10000000000.9999';`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel If I use Cast function in my sql to convert the value into a signed integer datatype php knows that it is an integer because if I return the value I can see in my network tab that it's an integer. So what you're saying is wrong.

Comment: How is that wrong, what I wrote? I was talking about DECIMALs, not INTEGERs. Now again and for the last time: MySQLs INTEGERs can be mapped to PHPs INTEGER without losing information/precision. The same can't be done for MySQLs DECIMALs, because PHP doesn't have a data type for fixed point numbers. Only strings can hold such numbers in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288519/eloquent-casts-decimal-as-string)

Maybe it resolves your question ? 
Regards

Comment: I have a raw query so this solution does not work for me because I'm not using eloquent so I can't define the attributes with the cast.