# issue with mysql save latitude and longitude (cut numbers) laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, leaflet, double

This working with mysql (5.7.32) php (8.0.0) and laravel 8.
I get lat and lng using leaflet. in fact I did tests saving the number manually in the database and the same error occurs

when I look at the database with phpmyadmin I see exactly the number it should be:
-32.84240531063937 but when I bring those values ​​with laravel and do dd() -32.842405310639
remove the last numbers (37).

the data type on mysql is DOUBLE without Length/Values

this is how i get the numbers from the database.

I have a table called complaints where each of them has lat and lng
So now I need to get all the records that have (comune_name = Llay Lay)
and it is from there where I get lat and lng from the first record.

```
$complaints = Complaint::where('comune_name', 'Llay Llay')->get()->toArray();

$denounced_lat = $complaints[0]['lat']; //lat of first complaint
$denounced_lng = $complaints[0]['lng']; //lng of first complaint

  dd($denounced_lat); //acá está el error
```

The number I see in the database is: -32.84240531063937
and the number that dd () draws is:  -32.842405310639

thnks :)

EDIT: Finally i save as VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to hold a long number after the comma ',' you can use [decimal](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-decimal):

```
    $table->decimal('lng', 10, 18);
    $table->decimal('lat', 10, 18);
```

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:

M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.

D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

it worth to say that you should cast it to float in $cast attribute in your model, in Laravel doc, there is a decimal cast but it's not ready yet!
for more info see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48288583/10573560).

see [mysql decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 0):

PHP works with different precision compared to your database solution.

Consider storing them as 64-bit signed ints if you want to keep the precision.

Comment: finally i save as VARCHAR, problem solved. thanks!